# ImportError: cannot import name '_literal_as_text' from 'sqlalchemy.sql.expression'

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, sqlalchemy

We are using SQLALCHEMY for our project and due to upgrade of SQLAlchemy we are getting below error

It would be really good if someone can help us :

Error message from worker: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 760, in run self._load_main_session(self.local_staging_directory) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 501, in _load_main_session pickler.load_session(session_file) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/apache_beam/internal/pickler.py", line 311, in load_session return dill.load_session(file_path) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 368, in load_session module = unpickler.load() File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 472, in load obj = StockUnpickler.load(self) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/dill/_dill.py", line 827, in _import_module return getattr(**import**(module, None, None, [obj]), obj) File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/beam_nuggets/io/relational_db.py", line 11, in  from beam_nuggets.io.relational_db_api import ( File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/beam_nuggets/io/relational_db_api.py", line 21, in  from sqlalchemy_utils import database_exists, create_database File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy_utils/**init**.py", line 1, in  from .aggregates import aggregated # noqa File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy_utils/aggregates.py", line 372, in  from .functions.orm import get_column_key File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy_utils/functions/**init**.py", line 1, in  from .database import ( # noqa File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy_utils/functions/database.py", line 10, in  from ..expressions import explain_analyze File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy_utils/expressions.py", line 4, in  from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import ( ***ImportError: cannot import name '_literal_as_text' from 'sqlalchemy.sql.expression' (/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/expression.py)***

Comment: @IljaEverilä : Not really, I have tried depreciating the packages but still not working.

Comment: Simply, you haven't pinned SQLAlchemy to <1.4.

Comment: I have explicitly mentioned SQLAlchemy to 1.3.15 
and ran pip freeze

Comment: Cannot reproduce. `from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import _literal_as_text` works with 1.3.23, and doesn't work with 1.4.2

Comment: @AnttiHaapala : I was using 1.13.15 till last week. It was working fine. 
I have frozen my requirements with 1.13.15 this week still doesnt work.

Comment: you need to reinstall 1.13.15

Comment: You must upgrade `sqlalchemy-utils>=0.36`.